# Mule 4 DataWeave Pass array to Db::createStruct

Tags: database, mule, dataweave, mule4

This is my payload:

```
[
  [
    2452,
    1,
    "AA",
    "SH289122275",
    "82310",
    "CB",
    "83.5"
  ],
  [
    3456,
    2,
    "BB ",
    "SH389122275",
    "92310",
    "BB",
    "83.5"
  ]
]
```

How to fit my payload into below transformation dynamically (i.e at. [111,"aaa"],[222,"bbb"]), I may get more objects in my payload.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    attribute: Db::createArray("Database_Config","DEMO_OBJECTS",[
        Db::createStruct("Database_Config","DEMO_OBJECT",[111,"aaa"]),
        Db::createStruct("Database_Config","DEMO_OBJECT",[222,"bbb"])
    ])
}
```

Comment: what is your required output? alos the format of input?
current input in question is not valid array and not a object. Please provide right input and output

Comment: Please provide more information. Input and Expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the structure and order of the data in the input. This is a possible example that you can adapt to your specific needs:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    attribute: Db::createArray("Database_Config","DEMO_OBJECTS",
payload map
     Db::createStruct("Database_Config","DEMO_OBJECT",[ $[0], $[1] ... ]))
}
```

Comment: How can we resolve the reference for Db::createArray? I am unable to find the method in Dataweave core functions.

Comment: It is not provided by DataWeave. It is contributed by the database connector. It would not make sense to use those functions in an application not using the database connector after all.